# Obter valores de um formato de array PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando obter alguns valores retornado de um array php mas não estou conseguindo! Pois acredito que o formato dele não está padronizado. Alguém tem uma ideia de como obter os seguintes valores desse formato de array?

```
array(5) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(4)
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["cn"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      int(1)
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Rouparia"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cn"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["dn"]=>
    string(41) "CN=Rouparia,OU=Grupos,DC=empresa,DC=local"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["cn"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      int(1)
      [0]=>
      string(25) "Spark - Coordenadores Adm"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cn"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["dn"]=>
    string(69) "CN=Spark - Coordenadores Adm,OU=Spark,OU=Usuarios,DC=empresa,DC=local"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["cn"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      int(1)
      [0]=>
      string(13) "Coordenadores"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cn"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["dn"]=>
    string(46) "CN=Coordenadores,OU=Grupos,DC=empresa,DC=local"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["cn"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      int(1)
      [0]=>
      string(18) "GR_CFS_Coordenacao"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cn"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["dn"]=>
    string(63) "CN=GR_CFS_Coordenacao,OU=Internet,OU=Grupos,DC=empresa,DC=local"
  }
}
```

Preciso obter apenas os valores: Rouparia, Spark - Coordenadores Adm, Coordenadores, GR_CFS_Coordenacao

Estou tentando um for não consigo obter apenas o valores:

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($groups); $x++){    
    $search = $groups[$x];    
    print_r($search);
}
```

Saido do for:

```
Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => Rouparia
        )

    [0] => cn
    [count] => 1
    [dn] => CN=Rouparia,OU=Grupos,DC=empresa,DC=local
)
Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => Spark - Coordenadores Adm
        )

    [0] => cn
    [count] => 1
    [dn] => CN=Spark - Coordenadores Adm,OU=Spark,OU=Usuarios,DC=empresa,DC=local
)
Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => Coordenadores
        )

    [0] => cn
    [count] => 1
    [dn] => CN=Coordenadores,OU=Grupos,DC=empresa,DC=local
)
Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => GR_CFS_Coordenacao
        )

    [0] => cn
    [count] => 1
    [dn] => CN=GR_CFS_Coordenacao,OU=Internet,OU=Grupos,DC=empresa,DC=local
)
```

Preciso obter apenas os valores nas chaves:

```
[0] => Rouparia
[0] => Spark - Coordenadores Adm
[0] => Coordenadores
[0] => GR_CFS_Coordenacao
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Analisei melhor a estrutura do Array e consegui obter os valores com a seguinte estrutura de repetição:

```
foreach ($groups as $val) {
    if (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) {
        foreach ($val['cn'] as $val2) {
                echo $val2 . "\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Resultado:

```
1
Rouparia
1
Spark - Coordenadores Adm
1
Coordenadores
1
GR_CFS_Coordenacao
```